# How do I change the Adaptive card once the user input is submitted?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Though there were few questions regarding the similar, I don't see any working solution.

I am working on a BOT for a feedback. Currently the user is able to send multiple responses by clicking on the options provided in the adaptive card. I am trying to replace the adaptive card with a plain adaptive card that just has some plain text like , "You have chosen option 3".

Comment: Here is the documentation for the same: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=dotnet#update-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following from the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=dotnet#update-messages) provided in above comments by subbu helps in resolving the same.

```
var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment(card.ToAttachment());
activity.Id = turnContext.Activity.ReplyToId;
await turnContext.UpdateActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);
```

We went with just deleting the card & sending a default response once user submits as that was enough.

Comment: can you please add the link as the answers will change in order over time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JosVerlinde thank you for the suggestion. I have added the link as hyperlink to the answer.